# Force redirect of URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to do the following:

Redirect anyone that visits http://domain.com/register?a=signup&say=done&
To:
http://domain.com/done

The reason I'm doing this is the script I'm using is encoded, so I cannot go in and change the PHP code to redirect users to /done whenever they finish registering. The way it currently is, /register is already being used to mask the following:

RewriteRule ^register/?$ index.php?a=signup [NC,L]

Is there any way to go about doing this?

Comment: Ive never heard of encoded php

Comment: @Jonasw http://www.ioncube.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a=signup($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)say=done($|&)
RewriteRule ^register$ /done? [L,R=301]
```